# Index for VARCHAR column has low efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two tables with relationship one to many.

```
create table locations
(
  id bigint 
     auto_increment 
     primary key,
  location_id varchar(128) 
     null,
  constraint locations_location_id_uindex 
     unique (location_id)
);


create table links
(
  id bigint 
     auto_increment 
     primary key,
  location_id varchar(128) 
     null,
  loc_id bigint 
     null,
  constraint links_location_id_fk 
     foreign key (loc_id) 
     references locations (id)
);

create index links_location_id_index
   on links (location_id);
```

The `locations` table has `596_752` records and `links` table has `1_221_450` ones.  Both tables are very often updated with a new data, there is no a deletion process. The `location_id` in both tables has size 30 characters.
When a new data appear in `links` table I have to find all `links.location_id` that do not exist in `locations.location_id`. In order to do so I execute the following query:

```
SELECT links.location_id 
FROM links
LEFT JOIN locations l 
   ON links.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE l.location_id IS NULL
```

The log output says:

```
34 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 m 11 s 678 ms (execution: 1 m 11 s 668 ms, fetching: 10 ms)
```

As you can see, it works too long and I am looking for a way how to improve it, can You help me?

**EDIT**
The info about MySQL server, it's `db.t2.micro` AWS instance:

```
innodb_version  8.0.13
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions  ""
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
version 8.0.13
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
version_compile_zlib    1.2.11
```

[image: EXPLAIN results]

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Your scheme is potentially contradictory. Nothing prevents to have the FK link between records by some `locations.id=links.loc_id` whereas the `links.location_id` in the same record is equal to the value of `locations.location_id` from another, not referenced, record. *The location_id in both tables has size 30 characters.* So why you use `varchar(128)` and not `char(30)`?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this and let me know if this improves your performance:

```
SELECT links.location_id FROM links 
WHERE NOT Exists( 
select location_id from locations);
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried your query `select distinct links. location_id from links where links. location_id not in (select distinct location_id from locations)`, it executes 3s but then I tried the query from the question and it executes 2s. What could be the reason?

Comment: Reasons for?  For improved performance of your query? would you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Yes, what could be the reason for improved performance?

Comment: Buffering of data into innodb buffer.  Second executions onward you will see a much 
 better performance.

Comment: Provide the `EXPLAIN` for both queries.  You _may_ find that they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR` is not the villain.  Having to scan 1.2M rows and do 1.2M lookups is the killer.

Why do you need to do this repeatedly?  You say you check the entire table every time you add one row?  Can't you just check the new row that you are adding?  Please elaborate on this -- it is the key to shrinking the time from a minute to a few milliseconds.

And what do you do with the resulting 34 rows?

Why have a `PRIMARY KEY` of a `id BIGINT`?  You may as well have `location_id` be the `PRIMARY KEY` in `locations`.  And, since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, you can then get rid of the unique clause.